# Issues using the_post_thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm teaching myself Wordpress, and my current goal is to display 4 thumbnails of images posted in a particular category.

I've already got the posts being pulled in by category, however I cannot pull ONLY the images. It's either the images and post text, or none at all.

My code is posted here: http://pastebin.com/NZ7fyyPA

I've tried simply replacing

`<?php the_content(); ?>`

with:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`

but that didn't work at all. Nothing came back at all!

I've even tried simply removing:

`<?php the_content(); ?>`

and same as above! I was thinking that because I have

`<div class="entry-thumbnail">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>`

That would pull the thumbnail in only, so I thought removing the content would help but nope!

I've read through the Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

and the only question I have from that, is that immediately the Codex says:

"Use get_the_post_thumbnail($id, $size, $attr ) instead to get the featured image for any post."

Which I don't think I'm doing, because I haven't setup anything related to a 'featured image' in my theme...or is what I'm trying to do considered using a featured image? I'm only uploading images and posting them inside of the blog posts.

Sorry for the long write up, I'm sure it's something simple!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack; however, it works.

While viewing your Wordpress website, use the browsers developer tools to target the 'post text'. You'll be able to see the `id` that is associated with that data-set.

Then, in your CSS. Target that `id` and use `display:none;`

**Example:**

```
#posttext {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking I might have to do it this way, if I do would it impact other posts being displayed on other areas of the same page? For example, the code above is used in my footer.php but in my home_page.php and blog.php I have other posts being pulled in, and I don't want to mess that up for any reason.

Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to toggle the 'post text' for one specific page, add specific CSS within that pages PHP file, not in the global file.

Comment: I found that wordpress had given these images classes already, so actually hardcoded ID's into the posts and was able to manipulate them as I needed through those means! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One more thing you can set a featured image from admin and call that image with this code `the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );`   and when you want to show anything from content part then you can call with this code simply. `the_content();`
you can also use excerpt for this as `the_excerpt();`

Thanks

Comment: This is neat, I didn't know that you could do that. I may have to reprogram my existing means when the time is right! Thanks!